# Where to find Material Light style in styles.xml for following elements?

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes

I am making a cm12 theme using eclipse. Everything is fine, just a few Material Light things that I want to turn into Material Dark.

I have changed the Settings and SubSettings to Material dark (Theme.Material). But, these items in settings are still using Material Light.
So where do I find style for 
- Mobile Network Settings
- Gesture Settings (from cm).

Here are screenshots of these two settings-
http://postimg.org/image/ojeh0b9n9/

http://postimg.org/image/b4hcet81p/